# How to clear a DropDownList c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying with this line of code :

```
comboxBox.items = null;
```

it's not working, i have an error.

Anyone can give me a hand ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
comboBox.items.Clear ();
```

or like this :

```
comboBox.dataSource = null;
```

depend if its datasource

if you want to show an empty selection , try this :

```
comboBox.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
comboBox.Items.Clear();
```

Should do the trick.

`Items` is a read-only property of the combo box, so you can't assign to it.